# jquery delay mouseOut effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble attaching a delay to my mouseOut function.  Here's the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.nav').mouseover(function() {
    $('.nav').css({ left: '160px' });
});
$('.nav').mouseout(function() {
    $('.nav').delay(600).css({ left: '0' });
});
});
```

I figured that adding the delay section in would do it... but it still behaves as though it wasn't there at all.

Suggestions?

**EDIT**

The suggested setTimeout function worked - but created a new problem.  This effect now triggers even when still over the selected '.nav' div.

Here's a jsfiddle of the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/TRL4w/

Comment: Delay only applies to effects. You'll want a setTimeout function.

Comment: Added a new answer here also, if you check the demo, was that the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.mouseover()` and `.stopPropagation();`

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('header').hover(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        console.log('in');
        $('.nav').css({
            left: '160px'
        });
    },function () {
        console.log('out');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.nav').css({
                left: '0px'
            });
        }, 2000)
    });
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SR7Zq/)

Comment: yup that did it.  Not sure how much I like the effect, now that I see it in action... ha

Comment: @user3180105, happy I could help. Even if you don't like it :P

Answer (score 6):

The delay() function only works with animations. Try:

```
$('.nav').mouseout(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){$('.nav').css({left: '0'});}, 600)
});
```

From the [.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) docs:

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to
>   cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native
>   setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use
>   cases.

Comment: Ok - this works to delay the effect, but creates a new problem in the process:  it triggers the effect even with the mouse still on the section (unless you don't move it at all, which defeats the purpose).

Comment: I'll post a jsfiddle to demonstrate